# crontab is giving only 2045 lines of output instead of 6000 lines

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I am executing one shell script with crontab which has to give more than 6000 lines output only it is giving output up to 2045 lines then coming out. when I run that shell script it is working fine giving more than 6000 lines

My script is not having any errors when run from bash. But when I run from crontab it is redirecting output up to only 2045 or 2046 lines.

my script file is with following line /script/scriptip.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '$2 ~ /10.169/ || $2 ~ /10.170/ {print $2}' /script/iplist.txt > /script/ipid.txt
```

my iplist.txt will have 18000 lines text

and my crontab entry is

```
 * * * * * /script/scriptip.sh
```

i run manually with

```
./script/scriptip.sh
```

Comment: Can you post your shell script?

Comment: Is the output of the first 2045 when running from the shell the same as when running from crontab?

Comment: There's probably an error occurring when started by cron. I suspect you have something established in your login environment that is absent in the cron environment. Or perhaps an error in your cwd assumption and file paths are incorrect. The output must differ at some point. run diff on both your outputs, it will be the first difference that is significant.

Comment: awk '$2 ~ /10.169/ || $2 ~ /10.170/ {print $2}' > /script/ipid.txt  when i run this same script from terminal it is executing fine

Comment: How do you start the script ? Both in your interactive session and show your crontab entry

Comment: my script file /script/scriptip.sh content is below               awk '$2 ~ /10.169/ || $2 ~ /10.170/ {print $2}' > /script/ipid.txt    and my crontab entry is                                   * * * * * /script/scriptip.sh

Comment: Please [edit] your question (do not add information in the comments) and include your `crontab` file. Make sure you include the correct command, the one you are showing now has no input file.

Comment: What **input** do you give the awk command?

Comment: sorry i forgot to type input file. now corrected

Comment: i am new to shell scripting and linux please suggest me

Comment: This might sound too obvious, but are you running the same script? `./script/scriptip.sh` is only the sane as `/script/script.sh` if you are in the root directory. What happens if you run `/script/scriptip.sh` manually.

Comment: Please, Don't test with a command that is different to crontab entry, `./script/scriptip.sh` is ambiguous since it depends on your Working Directory which we can not see, and then need to ask yet another question. We are working in the dark here and only have the information you supply.

Comment: Also a better place for your scripts ight be `/usr/local/bin` (or /usr/local/sbin` if it needs to be run as root).

Comment: Failing that, ask yourself how `/script/iplist.txt` changes over time. I assume the reason you want to run your script with cron is that it is regularly updated. To make a fair comparison you need to make sure that manual runs and cron runs of the script operate on the same `/script/iplist.txt` file.

Comment: With that crontab entry, it is going to truncate and rewrite `/script/ipid.txt` every minute. When you look at the file, is it perhaps in the process of being written to by the script?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think the problem is the difference between absolute and relative paths. You have not given us much to go on but I am guessing that you have a directory in your `$HOME` called `script` and that is where you keep your scripts.

So, you open a terminal (this opens in your `$HOME` by default) and run

```
./script/scriptip.sh
```

`.` means your current directory, so the command above actually runs

```
/home/kotesh/script/scriptip.sh
```

However, in your `crontab`, you need to use an absolute path since it will not be started from your `$HOME` directory. Try replacing your cron line with this one which uses the absolute path:

```
 * * * * * /home/kotesh/script/scriptip.sh
```

Also make sure that you are using absolute paths in the script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awk '$2 ~ /10.169/ || $2 ~ /10.170/ {print $2}' /home/kotesh/script/iplist.txt > /home/kotesh/script/ipid.txt
```

Comment: no my scripts are in / root folder not under /home/kotesh i did not told my script is not running with crontab. with crontab i am able to execute but instead of getting more than 6000 lines i am  getting only 2045 lines in my output file

Comment: @kotesh OK, and are you using absolute paths? You have `./script` in your question and that is confusing us.

Comment: @kotesh also, please show the _actual_ script, including the shebang line (the `!#/bin/sh` or equivalent) so we know how the script is being called.

Comment: when run the same script manually i am getting correct more than 6000 lines output. when scheduled crontab only i am getting only 2045 lines output

Comment: #!/bin/bash also added first line

Comment: @kotesh yes, I know. I read your question. I am asking you to show us the _entire_ script. I just tried this and it works fine, there is alsmot certainly a minor error somewhere but we can't help unless you show the exact things you are trying. Also, please don't add info in comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: please guide me to set environment for crontab

Comment: my script is with those two lines only. i thought that manually it was running fine. then i scheduled crontab then found when scheduled i am getting output in /script/ipid.txt but was ending at 2045 lines if i run it in terminal with bash or sh it was running fine and i am getting full 6000 lines output i think some crontab buffering is about 2048 lines or any environment issue. i dont know how to set crontab environment as bash. please guide me

Comment: @kotesh I don't think environmental variables are the source of you problem.

Comment: @kotesh, you could try clearing them all (except `PATH`) before running manually to see what happens, try `unset $(env | sed '/^PATH=/d; s/=.*//')`. If you are running your script with `sudo`, make sure you do `sudo -s` before clearing and running though.

Comment: i have given LOGNAME=root in crontab i wanted to run my script with root

Comment: @kotesh did you read Mark Plotnick's [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/crontab-is-giving-only-2045-lines-of-output-instead-of-6000-lines/116878?noredirect=1#comment181965_116863)? Could it be that the file is being overwritten? Also, I ask again, please [edit] your question and add the relevant files. You just tell us _now_, 24 hours later that you use `LOGNAME=root`. There is nothing in cron that should truncate like what you describe, I tried this and got >60000 lines of output. There must be something specific in your setup so **show us the _exact_ files!**.